# Prevent CREATE or DROP DEFAULT CONSTRAINT using DDL Trigger - SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

Can you please guide me how to **prevent** DROP or CREATE **ONLY** DEFAULT constraint on a table? DDL DB Trigger EventData isn't telling me what type of constraint it is (especially for DROP). Any pointers would be appreciated.

Some sample code

### Table script

```
-- A base table
create table testtrigger  (id int, dt datetime);
go

-- Audit event table
create table altertableaudit (id int identity, dt datetime default getdate(), eventdataddl xml);
go
```

### Database DDL Trigger code

```
--trigger code
create TRIGGER [trg_alter_table] ON DATABASE 
    FOR ALTER_TABLE
AS 
declare @EventData xml  = EventData();

insert into altertableaudit(eventdataddl) values (@EventData);

declare @isConstraintCreate bit = -1
        , @isConstraintDrop bit = -1 
        , @commandtext      nvarchar(max) = N''
        , @constraintname       sysname
        , @action               sysname
        , @Replicate            bit  = 1
        ;

select @isConstraintCreate 
            =case 
                when  @eventdata.exist('/EVENT_INSTANCE/AlterTableActionList/Create/Constraints') = 1 then 1 
                else 0
            end
     ,@isConstraintDrop 
            =case 
                when  @eventdata.exist('/EVENT_INSTANCE/AlterTableActionList/Drop/Constraints') = 1 then 1 
                else 0
            end
;

if @isConstraintCreate = 1
begin
    select @commandtext = @eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');
    if charindex('default',lower(@commandtext)) > 0
    begin
        rollback transaction;
        set @action = 'create constraint';
        set @Replicate = 0;
    end;
end;

if @isConstraintDrop = 1
begin
    select @constraintname = @eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/AlterTableActionList/Drop/Constraints/Name)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');
    select @constraintname;

    if exists(select * from sys.default_constraints sdf with (nolock) where lower(sdf.name) = lower(@constraintname))
    begin
        rollback transaction;
        set @action =  'drop';
        set @Replicate = 0;
    end;
end;

if @replicate = 0
    begin
        select [@isConstraintCreate] = @isConstraintCreate , [@isConstraintDrop] = @isConstraintDrop 
            , [@commandtext] = @commandtext , [@constraintname] = @constraintname , [@action] =@action;
        --insert into altertableaudit(eventdataddl) values (@EventData);
        select [@replicate] = 'this schema change cannot be replicated';
    end
else
    begin
        select [@isConstraintCreate] = @isConstraintCreate , [@isConstraintDrop] = @isConstraintDrop 
        , [@commandtext] = @commandtext , [@constraintname] = @constraintname , [@action] =@action;
        select [@replicate] = 'this schema change can be replicated';
    end;

GO
```

### Test code

```
-- Add a column to see if the trigger fires
alter table testtrigger add col1 varchar(10) null;
go

-- select from audit
select * from altertableaudit

-- Alter the table to add a new constraint
ALTER TABLE [dbo].testtrigger ADD  CONSTRAINT [df_col1]  DEFAULT @@servername for col1
GO

-- select from audit
select * from altertableaudit

-- Drop the above constraint
ALTER TABLE [dbo].testtrigger drop  CONSTRAINT [df_col1]
GO
-- select from audit
select * from altertableaudit
```

For the CREATE, I can easily find that its a DEFAULT CONSTRAINT by doing a wildcard search on the `commandtext`. But for DROP, I cannot check if it is a default constraint before allowing the ALTER operation to proceed.

### Environment details

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64) 
    Jun 15 2019 00:26:19 
    Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 17134: )
```

Comment: Merely curiosity, why do you want or need to do this?

Comment: @PhilipKelley, We have P2P replication set up between multiple servers. Our ID management for tables on each server is based of unique SEQUENCES (not IDENTITY columns) bound as DEFAULT constraints. I am trying to prevent a drop/create of constraint on one server affecting other server(s), so that I can on-the-fly update the definition of the SEQUENCE if need be.

Comment: "_But for DROP, I cannot check if it is a default constraint before allowing the ALTER operation to proceed._" DDL triggers execute after the DDL operation has occurred, so the default constraint getting dropped will no longer exist in `sys.default_constraints`. You would have to rely on naming standards for your constraints and parse EventData's CommandText to detect the name of the constraint(s) being dropped.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, Yes, thats what i've done, with strong naming conventions. My question was more around, if a ROLLBACK TRANSACTION can preserve the constraint (or that object), there must be somewhere we can check the object details that is being dropped. It might be in the T-Log, but can we read it easily and find out?